# Objective C - Split string into array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How would I do this? I'm new to Objective-C but I can't find anything that would help me do this.

```
NSArray *splitLine = [currentLine componentsSeparatedByString:@":%@",notNumber];
```

Where `notNumber` is a string that represents anything that isn't a number. So I want to separate a string where there are colons separated by strings that aren't numbers. (I want to avoid splitting at times i.e. `3:00pm`, but split at iCal parameters like `DESCRIPTION:` and `LOCATION:`.)

Comment: Does the colon after location and description have a space after it?

Comment: Unfortunately no! It will always be a string in the alphabet.

Comment: Okay. Because then you could have done @": " --- Can the time be any time, or is it always going to be on the hour?

Comment: The data varies. Sometimes it'll say "3pm" which is great, but other times it will say "3:00pm"

Comment: Ok. you could do something like (this is not code, just logic) if the number before the color's int value is not zero, because i believe letters have an int value of zero, and this may work because its never going to be zero o'clock

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several steps, like this. I have not compiled this code, but it should at least give you an idea of what to do.

1) Create a regex object to match your separators:

```
NSString *regexString = @"DESCRIPTION:\s|LOCATION:\s"; // or whatever makes sense for your scenario
NSRegularExpression *regex =
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                            error:nil];
```

2) Replace all the different separators matching your regex with just one separator:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSString *string2 = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                     options:0
                                                       range:range
                                                withTemplate:@"SEPARATOR"];
```

3) Split the string!

```
NSArray *elements = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"SEPARATOR"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest solution for splitting string.

```
NSString *str = @"Please split me to form array of words"; 
NSArray *wordsArray  = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions!

Using the pattern (I believe this is the core of your question):

```
pattern = @"(?<=[^0-9]):(?=[^0-9])"
```

This pattern will only match ':' symbols not surrounded by numbers.

Then replace with a dummy value that won't show in your data

```
dummy = @"NEVERSEETHIS"

NSRegularExpressions *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
NSString *modified= [regex replaceMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:range withTemplate:dummy];
```

and finally, split

```
return [modified componentsSeparatedByString:dummy];
```